# uploading an image and create a zip file doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, zip

Im trying to upload an image and create a zip file with this image, i watched any codes here, but I dont quite understand. Help, please.

PHP

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<?
require('conecta.php');
$uploaddir = '/var/www/subirImagenBD/';
$fechaFoto=date('YmdHis').'_'.basename($_FILES['Foto']['name']);
   if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['Foto']['tmp_name'])) {
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $fecha . $fechaFoto;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Foto']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    $cFoto=basename($_FILES['Foto']['name']);
   }
   echo $cFoto." guardada en ".$uploaddir. $fechaFoto."<br>";
   $cSQL="INSERT INTO FOTOS (NOMBRE,PIC) VALUES (?,?)";
   $stmt=$oConni->prepare($cSQL);
   $stmt->bind_param("ss", $fechaFoto, file_get_contents($uploaddir. $fechaFoto));
   $stmt->execute(); 
 /* 
   $zipFile = $fechaFoto;
$zipArchive = new ZipArchive();

if (!$zipArchive->open($zipFile, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE))
    die("Failed to create archive\n");

$zipArchive->addGlob($fechaFoto);
if (!$zipArchive->status == ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OK)
    echo "Failed to write local files to zip\n";

$zipArchive->close();*/


?>
```

Comment: $fechaFoto is purely the filename, without any directory reference.... unless your script is executing in the same directory as the file, then it won't be found by addGlob()... and why use addGlob() when you're only adding a single file anyway, why not simply add()?

Comment: @Mark Baker I will try it.

Comment: Always use `<?php` as php starting tag. You used `<?` here.

Comment: is this enough to run zip: apt-get install zlibc?

Answer (score 0):

please refer below link for zip a file

http://creativedev.in/2012/04/create-a-zip-file-in-php/

hope it helps